# How to properly include the directory in distutils

Tags: python, c++, api, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a pretty basic question regarding building Python extensions with C++. In one of my header files, I have a line `#include "veins_python/veins_python.h"`, which is a relative path that Python does not see. When I run `python setup.py build`, I get

```
In file included from MyVeinsAppRoss.cc:24:
MyVeinsAppRoss.h:25:10: fatal error: veins_python/veins_python.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include "veins_python/veins_python.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have tried to give an give an absolute path to `veins_python.h` in my `setup.py` file

```
module1 = Extension('MyTest',
                    include_dirs = ["~/veins_python_practice/src/veins_python"],
                    sources = ['MyVeinsAppRoss.cc']
                    )
```

and also the path just before the `veins_python` directory

```
module1 = Extension('MyTest',
                    include_dirs = ["~/veins_python_practice/src"],
                    sources = ['MyVeinsAppRoss.cc']
                    )
```

But the error does not change. Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it is that you have to type the home directory as `/home/username`, i.e. `~` will not work.